# HIve/Hadoop/Spark SQL ACID Transformations - How to Delete from table_a where table_a.id = table_b.id

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

SQL novice here trying to perform a delete operation using Hive syntax and ACID transformations
I have two delta files that I have brought in as dataframes in Databricks. Table_A and Table_B

Here's what's failing:

`DELETE FROM Table_A WHERE Table_A.id = Table_B.id`

Here's the error I get back
`AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Table_B.id`' given input columns: [];`

Table_B is a valid dataframe that is loaded into memory at the time of the query, and does have a schema with a single column ('id'). This error leads me to believe I'm not providing enough context and am failing to introduce Table B into the query correctly

I've read on here that I could possibly insert the rest of of rows (i.e., the ones I want to keep) into another table and then drop the old table, but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: `DELETE FROM Table_A WHERE Table_A.id IN (select Table_B.id from Table_B)`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do IN subquery to get the Table_B id's:

```
DELETE FROM Table_A WHERE Table_A.id IN (select Table_B.id from Table_B)?
```